Problem with Safe Wallet - Send ETH to a Safe Wallet of Wrong Chain
I created two safe multisig wallet in Ethereum (the 1st is 0xbc9977A62ac5DA7ED48239CD92ca0c7A2FFAd97B, and 2nd is 0xb393D80cAB42233Ba1E2EE1d0cac18e10e20ADD6), and I sent some ETHs to ADD6 multisig wallet in ARB chain. Then I tried to recreate same ADD6 address in ARB, it always failed. But it was success to recreated d97B safe wallet in ARB chain.  The method I used was the same(https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover)
Could anyone give me some advices or suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.
